# How to draw this circuit (or something similar) with circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

I've been playing around with `circuitikz`, and am really loving it so far.  The only problem is that I really don't know how to adapt it when there a symbol that I want is not present.

For example, I would like to draw the following circuit:

[image: A circuit]

The specific problem that I am having is that I don't know how to terminate both ends with a +5V and -5V symbol.   This is the best that I could come up with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american voltages,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
   \draw (0,0) to [battery,l=\SI{-5}{V}] (0,0)
               to [empty led,l=LED1] (0,3)
               to [R=\SI{510}{\ohm}] (0,5)
               to [battery,l=\SI{5}{V}] (0,5);               
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Another related question:
How do I flip the LED direction in the code above without starting from the top (0,5) and going to (0,0)?   I tried something like `[empty led,l<=LED1]` but that didn't work.

Thank you for any advice or suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

circuitikz uses tikz, so you can use the usual tikz constructs (such as `\draw`). Here's a simple version of the code producing what you need (of course, feel free to improve it according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american voltages,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
   \draw (0,5) to [R={\parbox{1cm}{R1\\\SI{510}{\ohm}}}] (0,3)
               to [empty led,l=LED1] (0,0);
  \draw (-0.5,0) -- node[anchor=north,align=center] {\SI{-5}{V}  \\ IR-LED } (0.5,0);
  \draw (-0.5,5) --  node[anchor=south] {VCC} (0.5,5)  node[anchor=west] {\SI{5}{V}};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Following a suggestion by Harish Kumar, you can flip the LED direction by interchanging its coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american voltages,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
   \draw (0,3) to [empty led,l=LED]  (0,0);  
   \draw (0,3) to  [R={\parbox{1cm}{R1\\\SI{510}{\ohm}}}, mirror] (0,5);
  \draw (-0.5,0) -- node[anchor=north,align=center] {\SI{-5}{V}  \\ IR-LED } (0.5,0);
  \draw (-0.5,5) --  node[anchor=south] {VCC} (0.5,5)  node[anchor=west] {\SI{5}{V}};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To flip the direction of LED, just interchange the co-ordinates. `\draw (0,0) to [empty led,l=LED1]  (0,3);` to `\draw (0,3) to [empty led,l=LED1]  (0,0);`

Comment: @HarishKumar: thanks! I've updated my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: It should be `\draw (0,0) to [empty led,l=LED1]  (0,3);` in the first line to flip the direction of LED in your second code.

Comment: Forgive me for editing your answer @Gonzalomedina. Did I edit properly?

Comment: @HarishKumar: no problem; you can freely edit ;-) However, I think the OP originally had the LED pointing as in your edit but wanted it flipped the other way around (as in my first example code)?

Comment: Oh.. I did not run his code. I was watching the picture he provided. Thanks for your kind reply.

Comment: Thank you Harish and Gonzola for all the suggestions.   This has been extremely helpful!

Just to be complete: I wanted to know if I could flip the LED direction without having to type an extra \draw command.  For example, to change the current direction in a resistor I can do:

    \draw (0,0) to [R,i<=$i$];

instead of 

    \draw (0,0) to [R,i=$i$].

It's no big deal, I was just seeing if I could be more efficient.   Thanks again for all the help!